# AJAX/JSONP Question. Access id denied using IE while requesting corss domain

Tags: ajax, jsonp

Ok, Here we go. I have already searched the Stack for the answer i have found some useful info but i want to clear up some more things. I also search the net for the answer but no real help.

1. I have worked with some api (yelp, ouside.in). In yelp i use to inject the script to head with the url request to the api with a callback funcion. I worked fine in all browsers. But while using outside.in api when i call the url the callback in not working.

In yelp they have a url field can be used like that callback=callbackfuncion so the callback will automatically called.

But in outside.in there is not such field available. Is there are any standard command for callback function which will work regardless of any server/api?

1. I also tried a standard ajax request using jQuery $.ajax() function. It worked for my local pc for both IE and other browser but did not working in IE showing the error: access denied, other borwser seems ok. Firebug in my FF also don't notice any errors.
2. Outside.in has an javascript example but it is too hard to me to understand

github.com/outsidein/api-examples/tree/master/javascript/browser/

site i am working: http://citystir.com
yelp: yelp.com
outside.in: outside.in

Techniqual info:

i am using: wampserver in local, wordpress for hosting, Godaddy, apache for remote with linux.

Codes:

Using Jquery $.ajax

url is like: `"http://hyperlocal-api.outside.in/v1.1/states/Illinois/cities/chicago/stories?dev_key="+key+"&sig="+signeture+"&limit=3`

```
function makeOutsideRequest(url){
$.ajax({
  url: url, dataType: 'json', type: 'GET',
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    if (data == null) {
      alert("An error occurred connecting to " + url +
        ". Please ensure that the server is running and configured to allow cross-origin requests.");
    }else{          
      printHomeNews(data);
    }
  },
  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert("An error occurred - check the server log for a stack trace.");
  }
});
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked in the Outside.in developer forums this morning as well (presumably by the same person). Here's a link to that discussion: http://developers.outside.in/forum/read/97053

To summarize, the Outside.in API does not support JSONP, but CORS support is included in the next release of the API, which will hit in the near future.

Comment: Hay! are you the same guy from outside.in?